# Creating dropdown with the first option only as heading

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a dropdown in such a way that the first option should be avaialable only as a heading.
eg:
   
           more Sectors
           Sector1
           Sector2

While displaying the dropdown it should be shown with "more Sectors " as the heading.On clicking the dropdown for selecting a particular option, the option "more Sectors" should not be available as an option.

Regards,
Ragesh Kumar A.K

Answer (score 5):

See whether the [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag is for you.

Comment: +1 Probably one of the least- known elements. I've seen so many input dropdowns with separators "-------------".